# Is there a way to pause querying in google data-studio while editing a report

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I’m building a bar chart in google data-studio in a report connected to BigQuery, calculating min, max, avg for a metric with one dimension. The problem is that every time I edit the chart to add the metric and change its calculation (for instance for sum to min), a BigQuery query is run which is very wasteful. So I was wondering if there is a way to pause the querying until I finish constructing / editing the chart before unpausing it to have the final query with the final chart.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the pre-fetch cache may lower costs: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?hl=en. But I'm not sure if that will stop queries from being issued during edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing your own [connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) using Apps Script and fetch data using the [BigQuery service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery). If you set up an intermediary [Apps Script cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/), you reduce the number of times you have to hit BigQuery.